# Running Flink stream application with a scheduler

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to run Flink stream job between 02:00-04:00 every day. Everytime, it should start from beginning of the stream until it process all data to s3 bucket after a join operation.

My application consumes data from topic and read data from s3 and joins it. After a filtering operation, it process new data object to s3 again.

How can set a scheduler for this job?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you using the batch or the stream processing operators of Flink?

Comment: Are you wanting to submit a daily job to an already running Flink cluster, or bring up a new cluster, run this job on it, and then tear it down?

Comment: I want to submit a daily job on running cluster. Yes indeed, I want to have it to be run in defined hours only and pause and then resume in the next day etc.

Comment: I am using stream processing. @PeterCsala